# PyQt5: MainWindow.move() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

Trying to have a custom header (QFrame) at the top of my window. I want to be able to click and drag said header, the same way you would drag a normal window around your screen. When I try to actually move the window by dragging the header, the error `MainWindow.move() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` appears in the console and the program crashes. I'm only passing in a single argument to the function but it keeps flagging the error anyway.

Here is the code I have that is causing the error.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSizeGrip
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow

# Slightly edited with basic names
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        ############################################################
        # Window configuration
        ############################################################
        self.setWindowTitle("Project")
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        uic.loadUi("src/ui/untitle.ui", self) # Get ui file
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        ############################################################
        self.borderFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.borderFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.borderFrame.setObjectName("borderFrame")

        # Move window
        def moveWindow(event):
            
            # IF LEFT CLICK MOVE WINDOW
            if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
                pos = self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.dragPos
                self.move(pos)
                self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
                event.accept()

        self.ui.borderFrame.mouseMoveEvent = moveWindow

        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
                self.dragPos = event.globalPos()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app    = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I were to add `self` as an argument for `moveWindow()` it will give the error that `event` is not passed.

Here is the code for the header:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSizeGrip
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, Window):
        # --- Border frame QFrame
        self.borderFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.borderFrame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 1261, 36))
        self.borderFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65")
```

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre] and ensure that the code is properly shown by checking the preview before submitting.

Comment: @musicamante This is a mre. What could I include to make it more reproducible?

Comment: @goose.mp4 your code doesn't instantiate the window.

Comment: @101 that would be because it's a code snippet. Would it be better If I included the instantiation?

Comment: @goose.mp4 to make it an MRE then yes :)

Comment: @goose.mp4 A MRE must be *both* minimal **and** reproducible, but yours is *not*: right now we cannot even *run* it, since it has indentation errors. Considering that, we cannot assume that the code you provided is sufficient, and you may have left out parts that are essential for the problem (maybe you also tried to override/overwrite `move` somewhere). So we need a code that we could easily copy, paste and run without any substantial modifications, which is something you should test on your own in the first place: create a new script, paste the example, and see if you can still reproduce it.

Comment: @goose.mp4 1. please use the *correct* name when using `@`, otherwise we won't be notified about replies; 2. your example is still **not** reproducible, since it has syntax errors and is incomplete; 3. you're not expected to edit pyuic generated files (as warned by the header you ignored and removed), but instead properly follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @musicamante I mean this politely but instead of just pointing out what I've done wrong, could you provide what could resolve this misunderstanding instead? I clearly did not properly understand what you require. And yes I'm aware I need to use the correct name when using an @, it was obviously a typo. To me, you just get a QFrame object on any window and use my provided code snippet on it to try and see if it drags the window around. I did not edit the pyuic file I took the code from it. Have you thought of anything that might be the culprit of my issue? If so I'd love to hear you're answer!

Comment: @goose.mp4 "taking" code from pyuic files is conceptually the same as editing them: they are not supposed to be **ever** touched, copied, merged or whatsoever; for what's worth, you could (should) even completely ignore their contents (except for pure learning purposes), and the *only* proper and accepted way of using those files is by *importing* as explained in the link above. And, with all due respect, I clearly explained what we need: some code that we can copy, paste and run in order to reproduce the problem; and your current code will **never** run, due to multiple syntax errors.

Comment: Why did you define `moveWindow` as a function inside the constructor `__init__`? Move it up one level, making it a method of the class, and give it `self` as a parameter because that's expected on a method. Then you can assign it to `self.ui.borderFrame.mouseMoveEvent` as `self.moveWindow`. Also note that there's nothing wrong with starting with someone else's code if the license on it allows that, but that you should never include code in your own project that you don't understand.

Comment: @Grismar Hi, thanks for the reply. I just tried this and unfortunately the same error occurs as described in the original problem. It was originally outside but I put it in the `__init__` function as a suggestion from my friend and had just left it there.

Comment: @goose.mp4 Please take your time to *carefully* read your question imagining you are *us*, and answer this question: are you *actually* able to copy its **exact** codes to the required files, run it and reproduce the problem you're talking about? And be aware that we are perfectly able to ignore some missing imports or other minor problems, but since your code has *so many problems* we cannot even be sure about where the problem actually is. The only way we have to help you is by having *reliable* code to start with: without that, we can do nothing at all.

Comment: @musicamante No, you really have not explained anything really. There are syntax errors and problems, defining their existence means you can clearly see them. I do not see them? Could you tell me what specifically is the issues? You can also edit the post to fix them since you've pointed them out 4 times instead. How do you expect me to provide the code for the header if I don't include the code for the header to make it so you can reproduce this code? I You seem more invested in how I ask a question instead of actually helping whatsoever.

Comment: @Grismar While normally discouraged, using a local function as an "override" for a method is not conceptually wrong, as long as it's done properly and with awareness. Besides, according to the OP, the problem resides on the `move()` function, which is raising an error that is not consistent with the code, even assuming it were valid (and it isn't), since calling `self.move()` on a widget shouldn't cause such an exception. So, the OP is probably doing something else wrong, but we don't know it until they provide what required.

Comment: @goose.mp4 No, I cannot nor will fix them, because, while they are probably not directly part of the issue, they're clear symptoms that the code you're providing is ***NOT*** the code that should reproduce the problem, so there is absolutely no point in touching a code that is invalid to begin with. For the last time: we can only help you if you provide a **valid** MRE. Did you try to do what asked above? Are you capable of running the *exact* code you're providing us? Copy your code above, paste into some files and ***try*** to run it. Then, you'll see what we do: an *unreproducible* example.

Comment: @musicamante That is quite literally exactly what I did **before** asking the question. That was my literal copy and pasted testing code with some comments removed. The rest of my code was removed (which is >90 lines) and I just isolated that code into a file, and took the same QFrame (header) in the pyuic via import and the same error occured. The 2nd snippet provided (pyuic snippet) is the from the pyuic itself. As for your confusion you're clearly displaying, I reciprocate since this makes no sense. What do you suggest from my code I could add that would possibly clarify any issues?

Answer (score 1):

Although commenters are correct that you're not providing what you should and your refusal to do so isn't very conducive to getting an answer, the pedantry and generally unhelpful nature of the discussion is a good example of why StackOverflow will likely soon be mostly replaced by some version of ChatGPT.

Having said that, the below is an example of the type of MRI that people were asking for, which has a working solution in place. If the below doesn't help to answer your question, please ask specific questions about it and what about it doesn't serve to answer your question:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QFrame


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Create the QFrame element and set its properties
        frame = QFrame(self)
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        frame.setFixedHeight(20)
        frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

        # Create a layout and add the frame
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(frame)
        vbox.addStretch(1)

        # Set the layout for the window
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        # Set window properties
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # Connect the mouse events to the moveWindow function
        frame.mouseMoveEvent = self.moveWindow
        frame.mousePressEvent = self.mousePressEvent

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Save the mouse position when clicking, as an offset for the movement
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.offset = event.pos()

    def moveWindow(self, event):
        # Note how this is a method of the Example class, not the frame, nor a function in the constructor
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            x = event.globalX()
            y = event.globalY()
            x_w = self.offset.x()
            y_w = self.offset.y()
            self.move(x - x_w, y - y_w)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # create the example window with the draggable QFrame
    Example().show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This creates a window, with a QFrame element that can be grabbed to drag the window arond.

Comment: I'll not answer anymore to the OP, but the problem remains: they asked about a specific error (`move()` not accepting the given arguments), which won't change much based on your answer: if properly fixed, the code of the OP **should** theoretically work considering the function signature, as python allows using such function overwriting that is technically perfectly fine. There's no point in answering with a different code that alters the actual question and is not directly related to the problem: there are already dozens of posts about moving windows based on mouse movements.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it'll unfortunately still take a "lot" of time until SO would be finally replaced by AIs: as long as an AI is trained on bad questions that still get answered, they'll keep giving bad results as they're doing now. Learning is about understanding problems, not giving final answers. OTOH, your code has an big issue: avoiding a persistent reference to the `Example` instance works just "out of luck" due to the complex interaction of Python with Qt ownership. If those methods overwrites get commented, the window will immediately disappear. And that too can be bad AI training.

Comment: It's clear why their function won't work, and I commented on that on the question. Their approach to the problem is inherently flawed, so I simply provided a straightforward way to achieve their stated goal "I want to be able to click and drag said header, the same way you would drag a normal window around your screen."  If you feel there's a question that is a duplicate of this one, you should link it and request the question be closed on that account @musicamante

Comment: "I want to be able to click and drag" is their **final** goal, but that is **not** what was being asked. If you go to your car repair shop saying "I want to go to New York, but my car won't start", their mechanic won't bring you to New York. And, again, what you pointed out is ***not*** the cause of the problem of the OP, because overwriting methods like that is technically perfectly fine from the Python point of view (even if often discouraged): [here](//pastebin.com/Fj2chRjP) you can see a modified version of your code that uses the same concept, and works **exactly** as expected.

Comment: That code demonstrates that the exception (which is the point -and title!- of the OP) is completely unrelated to method overwriting. Please take my comments sincerely: there's nothing wrong in *expanding* answers by providing better, working solutions of a "final goal": I actually do that *a lot*, but I usually write about the specific matter at hand *first*, then *eventually* provide improved code, sometimes adding even completely different, unrelated solutions for the initial purpose. This is a Q&A website, but its actual goal is learning; and learning isn't just about "giving the solution".